# restrict electron app to resize when width is below minimum limit

Tags: javascript, electron

i have a basic desktop app built in electron. My desktop app can be resizable but if when resizing the width decreases to 700px then it should not allow user to resize less than that width. I mean the resizing should be available only if the width is more than 700 px. I tried this using `mainWindow.setMinimumSize(700, 700);` but it did not work.

How can i restrict resizing for less than 700 px width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel like you could use `minWidth` property to achieve your goal. Try to pass it when you create your window.

```
const window = new BrowserWindow({
  minWidth: 700,
});
```

You could also use [setMinimumSize](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winsetminimumsizewidth-height) function.

Comment: setMinimumSize did not work but minWidth worked for me. Thank you.